# Synonym for "to calm"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, synonyms

There is a verb that sounds like kwel/quel that means "to calm". My best attempts to get a butchered spelling close enough that a digital dictionary can tell me the proper spelling are failures; and none of my thesauri have the word of which I'm thinking.

Can anybody help out a frustrated and spelling-challenged English speaker?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're awfully close. The word is [**quell**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quell).

> 1. to thoroughly overwhelm and reduce to submission or passivity <*quell* a riot>
> 2. quiet, pacify <*quell* fears>

Comment: Man!  40 seconds!

Comment: @drɱ65δ: Does that mean Martha owes everybody a Coke? I can't remember how this works.

Comment: How about we both get the same number of votes, and you get accepted for getting there first - sound like a plan?

Comment: I wish I could split the correct vote.  Sadly, I don't even have enough points to give mmyers an up-vote. :(

Comment: @Anonymous: [You do](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation), but as an unregistered user, you're not allowed to vote.

Comment: +1. To both of course ;-)  The funniest thing is that *quell* originally means to kill.

Comment: Hey!  The accept was changed! You didn't need my cookie!  Now I need yours!

Comment: @drɱ65δ: [Cookie!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fw89L.jpg)

Comment: Yum Yum[!](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39596/synonym-for-to-calm/39598#39598)

Answer (score 6):

The word is **[quell](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quell)**.  You'd certainly have found it by googling or dictionary-searching if it weren't for the fact that the acronym QUEL is all that comes up when you try to google "quel" or search a dictionary for it.